# AWS CloudFormation custom resources not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have created a custom resource to trigger an AWS Lambda function and get an instance id as output. The custom resource is not creating in CloudFormation.

```
     Code: 
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import json
          import boto3  
          import os

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', 'us-east-1')
            response = ec2.describe_instances()
            for reservation_data in response['Reservations']:
              for instance_data in reservation_data['Instances']:
                  for tags_data in instance_data['Tags']:
                    print(instance_data['InstanceId'])

      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 200

  MyFrontEndTest: 
    Type: Custom::lambdatrigger
    Properties: 
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt lambdaFunction3.Arn
      ActionType: MyFrontEndTest
Outputs:
  Message:
    Description: Gets the instance id 
    Value: !GetAtt 'MyFrontEndTest'
```

Comment: Can you add more details? The complete CloudFormation template would be a good start. But then also what do you mean by "not creating"? What's in the Lambda log? What's in the stack log?

Comment: my lambda function is triggering but the custom resource is in (Create in progress)

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical description of a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon CloudFormation Custom Resources need to **signal their completion back to CloudFormation** rather than simply returning a value.

This can be done with the [cfn-response Module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html), for example:

```py
ZipFile: |
  import json
  import cfnresponse
  def handler(event, context):
    responseValue = int(event['ResourceProperties']['Input']) * 5
    responseData = {}
    responseData['Data'] = responseValue
    cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, "CustomResourcePhysicalID")
```

If CloudFormation does *not* receive the signal, then the stack will eventually timeout and resources will be rolled-back.

Also, if you wish to view log information related to a custom resource, you might need to **assign a role to the Lambda function that can output to CloudWatch Logs**. For example, the default `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` includes:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do I search for the log? What should be its name?

Comment: @elena To see the log associated with an AWS Lambda function, open the function in the AWS Lambda management console, go to the **Monitoring** tab and click **View logs in CloudWatch**. It will take you to the log in CloudWatch Logs.